# Where can I see the logic of internal email validation check in Ant Design

Tags: antd

I understand that when we create a form using Ant Design, we can code it like:`<Form.Item name={['user', 'email']} label="Email" rules={[{ type: 'email' }]}>`

However, I can not find the way of how Ant Design validate it or using which regular expression as the pattern.

Do you know where should I get the reference from? I have checked the Rule API, but can not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antd uses `rc-field-form` and this form package uses [async-validator](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator) for validation.

The regex for email is as follow:

```
 /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+\.)+[a-zA-Z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]{2,}))$/,
```

You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/blob/master/src/rule/type.ts).